# How to test the interaction between a method and its two helpers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have the following structure of my `Java` code:

```
public MyClass {
    // some class variables
    ...
    private void process() {
        private MyObject obj; 
        ...
        obj = createHelper();
        ...
        messageHelper(obj, "One of several possible strings");
        ...  
        messageHelper(obj, "Another call with a different string");  
        ...
    }

    private MyObject createHelper {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        // some Setter calls
        ...
        return obj;
    }

    private void messageHelper (MyOject obj, String message) {
        ...
    }

}
```

I would like to test, that based on properties `obj` (that I would like to specify), `messageHelper()` receives the right string.  In other words I need to control the result of one method and have access to the parameters of the other.

I'm still very shaky with all this Mock/Stub/Spy stuff.

It seems to me that I need to `Spy` on `MyClass`, `stub` `CreateHelper()` with a "manually" created object and  not sure what for intercepting call parameters for `messageHelper()`.

Also I noted that [Wiki](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#wheretodeclareinteractions) cautions against using Spies:

> Think twice before using this feature. It might be better to change
>   the design of the code under specification.

So what would an appropriate *Spocky* way to accomplish the task?

**Slightly Refactored Code:** *(5/5/14)*

```
public MyClass {
    // some class variables
    private messageSevice = new messageService();
    ...
    private void process() {
        private MyObject obj; 
        ...
        obj = new MyObject(parameters ...);
        ...
        if (someCondition) {
            messageService.produceMessageOne(obj);
        }
        ... 
        if (otherCondition) { 
            messageService.produceMessageTwo(obj);  
        {
        ...
    }

}

public class MessageService implements IMessageService {

    private final static MSG_ONE = "...";
    private final static MSG_TWO = "...";
    ...

    public void produceMessageOne(MyObject obj) {
         produceMessage(obj, MSG_ONE);
         ...
    }
    public void produceMessageOne(MyObject obj) {
         produceMessage(obj, MSG_TWO);
    }

    private void produceMessage(MyObject obj, String message) {
         ...
    }    
}
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone suggests the way it should be tested with **Spock**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caution you're referring to is rightfully there. There's a very good correlation between testable code and good design (I recommend watching this lecture from Michael Feathers to understand why http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cVZvoFGJTU).

Using spies tends to be a heads up for design issues since it usually arises from the impossibility of using regular mocks and stubs.

It's a little hard to predict from your example, since you're obviously using pseudo names, but it seems that the design of the `MyClass` class violates the single responsibility principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), since it does processing, creation and messaging (3 responsibilities).

If you're willing to change your design, so that the processing class (`MyClass`) will do only processing, you'll be providing another class that does the creation (`MyObjectFactory`), and yet another class that does the messaging (`MyObjectMessager`) either through a constructor, setter methods or by dependency injection.

Using this new design, you can create an instance of the class you're testing (`MyClass`), and pass it mock objects of both the factory and messaging classes. Then you'll be able to verify whatever you want on both.

Take a look at this example (using Mockito):

```
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void testThatProcessingMessagesCorrectly() {
        MyObject object = mock(MyObject.class);
        MyObjectFactory factory = mock(MyObjectFactory.class);
        when(factory.createMyObject()).thenReturn(object);
        MyObjectMessager messager = mock(MyObjectMessager.class);

        MyClass processor = new MyClass(factory, messager);
        processor.process();

        verify(factory).createMyObject();
        verify(messager).message(EXPECTED_MESSAGE_1);
        verify(messager).message(EXPECTED_MESSAGE_2);
        ...
        verify(messager).message(EXPECTED_MESSAGE_N);
    }

    ...
}
```

Here's a Spock example (untested, double check before using ...):

```
public class MyClassSpec extends Specification {
    def "check that the right messages are produced with the expected object"() {
        given:
        def messageService = Mock(IMessageService)
        def testedInstance = new MyClass()

        testedInstance.setMessageService(messageService)

        when:
        testedInstance.process()

        then:
        1 * messageService.produceMessageOne(_)
        1 * messageService.produceMessageTwo(_)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's a good idea to create a separate `MessageService` class that will have a separate method for each type of messages.  I do not believe I need a factory, since `MyObject` is quite capable of creating its own instances as long as I add necessary overlaid constructors and pass them required parameters.

Comment: What do the `messageOne()` and `messageTwo()` methods of `MyClass` do ? Do they simply call the methods of a member variable of the `IMessageService` type ? By the way, I completely failed to notice that you wanted a Spock solution, I'll try to brush off my Spock skills and write an example in Spock after you answer these questions.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to save my edit. These methods belong to `MessageService`.

Comment: Now it seems self-descriptive.

Comment: I've added a Spock example. Your class still needs some refactoring, since at the moment it creates all the instances it uses (i.e. the `MyObject` and `MessageService`) instead of getting them from outside. It's been a while since I wrote Spock, so treat it accordingly :-)

Comment: `process()` is actually producing different messages depending of values in `obj`.  So do I need to stub `MyObject` constructor?

Comment: I don't think you can stub a constructor. I would make sure that I get the instance of `MyObject` from outside the `MyClass` class. If you had a factory for `MyObject` instances for example, you could've stubbed the factory methods and ... voila.

Comment: You are wrong but right. We can [stub a constructor in Spock](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#mocking-constructors) but it's not advised.  I did additional refactoring/decoupling along the lines of your suggestion to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

### If you're a hammer, every problem is a nail

I'd like to call exception-to-the-rule here and say that sometimes stubbing private methods - necessitating spies - can be both correct and useful.

@eitanfar is most likely accurate in his analysis of the function, and 95% of the time this is the case, but as with most things - I believe - not always.

This is for those of us who believe they have an exception but get the usual "code smell" argument.

My example is a complex argument validator. Consider the following:

```
class Foo {
    def doThing(...args) {
        doThing_complexValidateArgs(args)
        // do things with args
    }

    def private doThing_complexValidateArgs(...args) {
        // ... * 20 lines of non-logic-related code that throws exceptions
    }
}
```

- Placing the validator in it's own class IMO seperates the concern too much. (a `FooMethodArgumentValidator` class?)
- Refactoring out the validation arguably significantly improves readability of the `doThing()` function.
- `doThing_complexValidateArgs()` should not be public

The `doThing()` function benefits from the reability of a simple call `validateArgs(...)` and maintains encapsulation.

All I need to be sure of now is that I have called the function within the parent one. how can I do that? well - correct me if I'm wrong - but in order to do that, I need a `Spy()`.

```
class FooSpec extends Specification {
            class Foo {
        def doThing(...args) {
            doThing_controlTest(args)
            doThing_complexValidateArgs(*args)
            // do things with args
        }

        def doThing_controlTest(args) {
            // this is a test
        }

        def private doThing_complexValidateArgs(...args) {
            // ... * 20 lines of code
        }
    }

    void "doThing should call doThing_complexValidateArgs" () {
        def fooSpy = Spy(Foo)

        when:
        fooSpy.doThing(1, 2, 3)

        then:
        1 * fooSpy.doThing_controlTest([1,2,3]) // to prove to ya'll we got into the right method
        1 * fooSpy.invokeMethod('doThing_complexValidateArgs', [1, 2, 3]) // probably due to groovy weirdness, this is how we test this call
    }
}
```

Here is my real life example I used for a static private method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("GroovyAccessibility")
@ConfineMetaClassChanges(DateService) // stops a global GroovySpy from affecting other tests by reseting the metaclass once done.
void "isOverlapping calls validateAndNormaliseDateList() for both args" () {
    List list1 = [new Date(1L), new Date(2L)]
    List list2 = [new Date(2L), new Date(3L)]
    GroovySpy(DateService, global: true) // GroovySpy allows for global replacement. see `org.spockframework.mock.IMockConfiguration#isGlobal()`

    when:
    DateService.isOverlapping(list1, list2)

    then:
    1 * DateService.isOverlapping_validateAndNormaliseDateList('first', list1) // groovy 2.x currently allows private method calls
    1 * DateService.isOverlapping_validateAndNormaliseDateList('second', list2)
}
```